# Minimize button is missing on Unity

Tags: unity, window-decoration

This error happens on both Unity 3D and Unity 2D. I tried `unity --reset` command but it doesn't fix the error. Gnome shell properly shows all three buttons minimize maximize and close. But Unity doesn't show it properly. How to fix this error?

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What do you get for this command? `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout`

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd> shortcut and type the below command and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it should fix the problem.

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
```